# Auto increment with XQuery Update?

Tags: xquery, auto-increment, basex, xquery-update

Does `XQuery` Update support auto increment attributes, just like auto increment fields in `SQL`?

I'm using `BaseX` as my database.

Comment: No, I had to do this in the application instead of in the database.

Comment: ...and then use some other database to generate the unique id's for you? As an XQuery updating statement cannot be combined with returning some value, I even fail to implement some "database sequence" in an XML database...

Comment: See Christian's comment to my answer. (I might rewrite my answer at a later time, if he does not post something himself here.)

Comment: My solution was a lot simpler, since the application I was writing was the only one with direct access to BaseX, so I could keep the current ID in my application.

Answer (score 2):

Given [an answer from Christian Grün on the BaseX mailing list](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2010-May/000259.html), this is doable when the node one is adding is defined in the XQuery Update statement, and hence can be enhanced using an `{enclosed expression}` *before* inserting it:

> You might specify the attribute counter within your XML file/database
>   and increment it every time when you insert an element. A simple
>   example:
>
> input.xml:
>
> ```
> <root count="0"/>
> ```
>
> insert.xq:
>
> ```
> let $root := doc('input.xml')/root
> let $count := $root/@count
> return (
>   insert node <node id='{ $count }'/> into $root,
>   replace value of node $count with $count + 1  
> )
> ```

I've not been able to achieve the same with an external `org.w3c.dom.Document` created in Java, and added to the XML database using XQJ and `declare variable $doc external`. Here, one might be tempted to update the "auto-increment" data after adding the document. However, the processing model defines that changes are not visible until all the commands have been queued (the [Pending Update List](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Pending_Update_List)). Hence a new document or node is, by definition, simply not visible for updates in the same FLWOR expression. So:

```
db:add('db1', '<counters comment-id="0"/>', 'counters')
```

...followed by repetitive executions of the following, will NOT work:

```
let $doc := document{ <note id=""><text>Hello world</text></note> }
let $count := /counters/@comment-id 
return (
  db:add('db1', $doc, 'dummy'), 
  replace value of node $count with $count + 1
  for $note in /note[@id=''] 
    return replace value of node $note/@id with $count (: WRONG! :)
)
```

Above, the last inserted document will always have `<note id="">`, and will not be updated until the next document is added. (Also, it would not work when somehow multiple documents with `<note id="">` would exist.)

Though in the example above one could successfully delete the `for $note in ...` part and use:

```
let $doc := document{ <note id="{ $count }"><text>Hello world</text></note> }
```

...I had no luck setting `<note id="{ $count }">` in the Document in the Java code, [as that enclosed expression would not be replaced then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697957/can-i-make-xquery-evaluate-expression-within-variables-bound-with-xqj).

Finally, some [state for similar solutions](http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2011-December/009284.html):

> [...] perform badly as it will lock out concurrent updates. You should consider using xdmp:random() to generate a 64 bit random number for your unique identifier.

In our case, the id would also be used in URLs; not too nice then.

See also [XRX/Autoincrement File ID](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XRX/Autoincrement_File_ID#Adding_and_Incrementing_an_Attribute) and [Using XQuery to return Document IDs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/eXist#Using_XQuery_to_return_Document_IDs).

Comment: Main-memory updates of documents may help here; please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697957/can-i-make-xquery-evaluate-expression-within-variables-bound-with-xqj/13212103#comment17990896_13212103 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on the implementation of the underlying data-store, because the auto-increment attribute is on the column definition in relational databases.

Probably, "yes".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added more information to the question.